# Tensorflow models/slim eval_image_classifier.py Number of images evaluated wrong

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I followed the [tutorial](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/slim) to finetune the inception model for the Flowers dataset.

The flowers dataset has 350 validation images specified in the flowers.py file.

But when I ran [eval_image_classifier.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/slim/eval_image_classifier.py) and modified it to print the number of TP,FP,TN,FN

The results:

```
I tensorflow/core/kernels/logging_ops.cc:79] eval/TrueNegatives[64]
I tensorflow/core/kernels/logging_ops.cc:79] eval/TruePositives[286]
I tensorflow/core/kernels/logging_ops.cc:79] eval/FalsePositives[2]
I tensorflow/core/kernels/logging_ops.cc:79] eval/FalseNegatives[48]
```

If you add the them up, its a total of 400. But the number of validation images is 350.

I did fine tuning for my custom dataset, where the validation images were 150 with only two classes.

The results were:

```
I tensorflow/core/kernels/logging_ops.cc:79] eval/TruePositives[11]
I tensorflow/core/kernels/logging_ops.cc:79] eval/TrueNegatives[155]
I tensorflow/core/kernels/logging_ops.cc:79] eval/FalsePositives[4]
I tensorflow/core/kernels/logging_ops.cc:79] eval/FalseNegatives[30]
I tensorflow/core/kernels/logging_ops.cc:79] eval/Accuracy[0.83]
I tensorflow/core/kernels/logging_ops.cc:79] eval/AreaUnderCurve[0.62156773]
```

If you add them up its comes out to be 200.

Why is this happening? Where are the additional 50 images coming from?

Is there a way to modify eval_image_classifier.py to print the name of the validation images with its predictions and labels?

I have also asked this question as an issue on the models/slim github but I have not received any response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason of the number of image mismatches is the input queue the program is using. It feeds values with batches. You need to set the `batch_size` and `num_batches` as per your dataset size to solve this problem. [num_batches](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/slim/eval_image_classifier.py#L185).

default value is upper rounded [deafult num_batches](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/slim/eval_image_classifier.py#L172)

Comment: Ok thanks. I will try that. For my custom dataset I have 150 images. So I have to change `batch_size= 75`?

Comment: you may set `batch_size` to any number as long as you are in synchronized with `num_batches` argument.